# Major Clipping Issue With Dress

Tags: animation, weight-painting, clipping

I’m new to blender. I have been facing a lot of clipping issues when creating a dress for decentraland. I tried using the transfer weights option in the weights tab in weight paint mode, but I am only able to transfer weight between the dress and the upper body or the dress and the lower body (not both), so the dress still has tears. I also tried removing skin faces underneath the dress, but the dress is open at the bottom so that doesn’t work. Do any of you have suggestions? Any feedback is appreciated.

In Blender Without Animation:
[image: Dress in Blender]

With Animation:
[image: Picture in Decentraland]

Applying Transform Weights:
[image: Transform Weights]

Comment: Can't you duplicate & join the upper and the lower body as a working copy and then transfer the weights to the dress?

Comment: You could mask the part of the body with a Mask modifier for example. Also you could give a shape key to the dress in order to avoid the clipping when it happens. Also a good tuto about cloth: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbyfuW5Aocg